# What is the best approach for the purpose to save the value of the variables and to get them passed between the WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, records

I am currently working on a C# project in which I got a couple of WinForms (currently 5 windows).

From these windows, I need to save all the information that has been filled(all the text from textBoxes, comboBoxes, dataGridViews, checkBoxes). In each window, there is control containing data I will need later to generate a script.

So my question is: **What is the best approach for the purpose to save the value of the variables and to get them passed between the WinForms?**

For now, I am storing the data from the controls in variables, but I believe there is much better and efficient way of doing this. (And also the variables are passing between the screens. So basically if I have in screen1 variable A, I need to access it from screen2 where there is another variable B, screen 3 needs A and B and variable C appears there, and so on ....)

I've been thinking about:

1. Saving the data in a text file(which I would like to NOT do it.)
2. User Settings (but I am pretty sure I cannot store the data from the grid in it. *If I am mistaken I will appreciate letting me know!*)
3. And the last one I mentioned I am using - passing variables between the WinForms.

Comment: Database?????..

Comment: Use a small local DB

Comment: Are you talking about dataset ?

Comment: The thing is: the application I'm working on is for creation on small scripts depends of the imput of the user. And later these scripts to be executed in the database. It is not possible for the project to use local DB.

Comment: @GratsielaGeshewa No, he is talking about a database. Like an access database, a SQL Server based database, SQLite, something like that. Never heard of them?

Comment: It is basically a wizzard, so it's only until the forms have been completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dto-class for each window, put data from window's control to corresponding dto and then serialize it.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: That did the job, thanks!

Comment: And how does it get stored to be accessible from the other screens?